# HAProxy SSL Redirect Loop

Tags: http, nginx, https, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy for load balancing the traffics. It works perfect for HTTP request but however it shows this webpage has a redirect loop on HTTPS. How to solve this looping?

[image: HAProxy Configuration]

Answer (score 1):

Your httpsclient backend isn't being used in your current config (all traffic is going to the http backend because its set to default and you have no rules that would map it to a specified backend) try mapping a rule like this maybe:

```
acl http_80   dst_port 80
acl https_443 dst_port 443

use_backend httpclient if http_80
use_backend httpsclient if http_443
```

(add this at the bottom of your frontend params, just above your first backend)